# Photos has been "stuck" scanning people's faces for several weeks

Tags: photos, scanning, photos.app

On all of my devices (Macbook, iPad, iPhone), when I go to **Photos -> People**, I am greeted with this message:

---

[image: 48k Photos Scanned, 10k Photos remaining]

---

I don't know how long this has been happening for, but I first noticed this about a month ago.

Needless to say, overnight I leave my devices locked, connected to power, and to wi-fi. The number of photos remaining doesn't seem to change – I don't remember if it remains exactly 10,655 but I do remember a month ago it was slightly over 10k.

Strangely enough, new photos are scanned just fine. The pictures I've taken yesterday were scanned correctly and faces were automatically detected. I am not sure which pictures have not been scanned or why.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? What do you suggest I could try to fix it or investigate it further?